# Need to add URL patterns to include in JMeter for Specific URL Substring

Tags: jmeter

I need to record only URLs having `jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search` in the Entire network request.

Please let me know how can I fulfill the same with the URL patterns to include option of Jmeter in "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder"

```
...../csuser/eam2/search/**jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search**1_1413442824.2983
...../csuser/eam2/search/**jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search**1_1413442824.2983/results_preview

...../csuser/eam2/search/**jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search**2_1413442824.2993
...../csuser/eam2/search/**jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search**2_1413442824.1983/results_preview

...

...../csuser/eam2/search/**jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search**N_1423442824.2983
...../csuser/eam2/search/**jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search**N_1423442884.2983/results_preview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following line into your [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)  `Patterns to Include` input:

```
.*(jobs\/csuser__csuser__eam2__search)$
```

and only those requests, which have `jobs/csuser__csuser__eam2__search` but in path will be recorded.

See [Excluding Certain Domains from the Load Test](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/140841-excluding-certain-domains-from-the-load-test) for more details, the approach is the same but you'll need to do the opposite thing.